# Query in SQLite with String

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to retrieve the phone number from a contact name. so i have this code

```
public String getPhoneNumber(String name) {
    String phonenumber = "";
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            "DISPLAY_NAME LIKE '%" + name + "%'", null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        //
        // Get all phone numbers.
        //
        Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID
                + " = " + contactId, null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String number = phones.getString(phones
                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
            int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
            switch (type) {
            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                //phonenumber = number;
                // do something with the Home number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                phonenumber = number;
                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                //phonenumber = number;
                // do something with the Work number here...
                break;
            }
        }
        phones.close();
        //
        // Get all email addresses.
        //

    }
    cursor.close();
    return phonenumber;
}
```

But, if the contact name is not match exactly with name in db, it will return nothing. So whether there have any way to retrieve the phone number even the input name is not very likely to?

for example, there have an contact :  Prototype Alex  and my input name is: prototype or alex.

Comment: `'Prototype Alex' LIKE '%prototype%'` is true (if that was valid syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to your concrete problem, but it might be helpful though. There are algorithms for [approximate string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) like the Levenshtein distance, soundex or metaphone.
Maybe it might be an option for you, to get all contacts from the content provider and then do the search with one of these algorithms.

Comment: I found another problem !, if the name of contact is "Ân" (unicode character), then i try to query with "ân" or "Ân" , the return data is null.However, the return data is correct if i used "=" instead of "like". So what should i do ?